# How much does Dynamics NAV 2009 cost?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-gp, navision

My company is evaluating becoming a Microsoft Dynamics Partner to do Dynamics installs.  We'll probably start with NAV 2009, because it seems to be the easiest to develop for.  However, we can't even find out what a typical Dynamics NAV 2009 license costs.  This is pretty important for us to know so that we can start to identify our market before investing in training, etc.

Does anyone know how much Dynamics NAV 2009 costs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ballpark about $2300 per user plus $6000 for the server install & basic training.

I **highly** recommend finding an MS Partner and talk to them about how your business works now and what you want to accomplish; and not not try to *do-it-yourself*. The various Dynamics products (AX, NAV, SL, & GP) all cost around the same amount, but the accounting flows differently. AX is geared for multinational companies. SL for job/project based companies. NAV is geared toward retail. GP toward service companies. All are highly customizable and in most situations come with CRM Server as well, which can be a huge benefit depending on how you use it.

*Shameless plug:* I work for [an MS Partner](http://www.ehtc.com/ehtc/tshome.htm) who specialized in SL & GP (plus CRM). You can [contact us](http://www.ehtc.com/ehtc/contact.htm) if you want more info, and if you're set on NAV we'll know people in your area that specialize in it.